# Posting a GIF to Tumblr from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, tumblr

There doesn't appear to be a straight forward way to post a GIF to Tumblr from an iPhone device?

I use the `TMTumblrSDK` for oauth authentication, but I haven't found a way to get a GIF posted to Tumblr after authenticating.  Using the `post:` methods always give me an error.

Not only that, but it appears even the native client doesn't post GIFs correctly, so I'm wondering if GIFs can even be posted from mobile.

Here is the main chunk of code that matters:

```
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerKey = @"consumerKeyHere";
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthConsumerSecret = @"secretHere";
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthToken = @"token";
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthTokenSecret = @"tokenSecret";

[[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] authenticate:@"testApp" callback:^(NSError * error) {
    //authenticating works

    [[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] userInfo:^(id userInfo, NSError *error) {

        //userInfo works

        NSString * stringData = [gifData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        [[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] post:@"myTumblrDomain.tumblr.com" type:@"photo" parameters:@{@"data": stringData,
                                                                                    @"tags": @"test",
                                                                                    @"caption": @"Test caption"} callback:^(id moreInfo, NSError *error) {
            //401 here.  Works if I use a text post instead
            NSLog(@"Post Info %@ Error %@", moreInfo, error);
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Can you add what you have tried and the errors you are getting?

Comment: Ya it appears when I try to post a photo using OAuth I get a 401, but a text post will post successfully.  Could Tumblr just not allow oAuth photo upload?

Comment: As far as I am aware all post types are supported with `post`.

Comment: I added code. Maybe that can help.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but this maybe of some help: https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK/tree/master/Examples/PhotoPostExample/PhotoPostExample